# Updation of corresponding numeric values for duplicate entries

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a shiny app where i have multiple input fields as `Scenario`, `Area_Crop`, `Area_Water` and `Area_Forest`. Now the `Scenario` field can have duplicate entries but the other fields have different numeric values corresponding to the duplicate values in the `Scenario` field. The problem is I am not able to update the `numericInput` value for each of the duplicate entry. When the selection is made for the duplicate entries the numeric values are not updated and remained blank.

I have used the `selectize` argument in the `selectInput` to render the duplicate entries which successfully did its job but the subsequent numeric update is not happening even after wrapping the `updateNumericInput` in the `observeEvent`. The `observeEvent` however works for non-duplicate entries but not for duplicate entries and I don't know why. In code I tried to update numeric input based on the value from the Scenario field. I have recreated the code to be a very basic one along with a sample data frame with both duplicate and single entries.

```
   df <- data.frame(Scenarios = c(rep("Land",3),"Land_1"), Area_Crop = 
   c(100,200,300,400), Area_Water = c(40,50,60,70), Area_Forest = 
   c(150,250,350,450))

   library(shiny)

   ui <- fluidPage(h4("Updating duplicate entries"),
            selectInput("scenario", "Scenario", df$Scenarios, selectize = 
                         FALSE),
            numericInput("crop", "Crop Area", min = 0, max = 1000, value 
                         = df$Area_Crop, step = 0.5),
            numericInput("water", "Water Area", min = 0, max = 1000, 
                         value = df$Area_Water, step = 0.5),
            numericInput("forest", "Forest Area", min = 0, max = 1000, 
                         value = df$Area_Forest, step = 0.5)
           )

     server <- function(input, output, session) {
               observeEvent(input$scenario,
                updateNumericInput(session,"crop", "Crop Area", 
                 max= 50000, min= 0, value =
                 df$Area_Crop[df$Scenarios ==input$scenario],step = 0.1))

                observeEvent(input$scenario,
                 updateNumericInput(session,"water", "Water Area",     
                  min = 0, max = 1000,value =
               df$Area_Water[df$Scenarios==input$scenario],step = 0.1))

              observeEvent(input$scenario,
                  updateNumericInput(session,"forest", "Forest Area", 
                  min= 0, max = 1000,value = 
               df$Area_Forest[df$Scenarios==input$scenario],step = 0.1))
            }

         shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

As you can see after running the code, that the single entry i.e `Land_1` is getting updated but not the duplicate entry i.e `Land`. I want this duplicate entries to also get updated with their corresponding row values.

It has been a while that I tried to solve this problem but without any success. I am new to R and Shiny so, any help from anyone would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your `numericInput` lines, you provide a vector (`df$Area_Crop`, etc., n = 4) to the `value` argument. `numericInput` is for 1 value. What would you expect `numericInput` to do with 4 values?

Did you notice your console? While running the code, it gave plenty of warnings that something was amiss. 3 times, actually. That's a hint that you are doing the wrong thing 3 times. So, find the error by commenting out 2 of 3 of almost identical things, and see if the warnings continue. When it does, you only have to look at 1 out of 3 duplicates to find the origin of your errors.

Next, you have 3 duplicate entries. `input$scenario` can take the value "Land", "Land", "Land", or "Land_1". How do you expect to distinguish between "Land", "Land" and "Land"?

This is what happens in your subsetting expression: `[df$Scenarios==input$scenario]`. On the right, you have a single value, on the left `df$Scenarios` which is a vector with the values "Land", "Land", "Land", and "Land_1". What is the outcome of that expression when `input$scenario` is "Land"? Which leads to the next question of what is the outcome of the expression `df$Area_Forest[df$Scenarios==input$scenario]` when `input$scenario` is "Land"? And what happens when you use that outcome for the argument `value` which expects a single value?

As you are new to R, I am not directly answering your question because you need to learn to debug your code and learn from these mistakes. But the answers are heavily hinted in the above.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Does this mean that I create Unique IDs for my duplicate entries and then select these IDs for updating the value in numericInput?

Comment: That sounds like a much safer method than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As [MrGrumble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/882102/mrgumble) mentions, you have a lot to learn. Having said that, I have hacked a way for your code to work by using `names()`. This is a little complicated so work through the code carefully and please feel free to ask any questions you may have. Again this is a hack but your duplicate values make it very difficult to work around.

```
df <- data.frame(Scenarios = c(rep("Land",3),"Land_1"), Area_Crop = 
                     c(100,200,300,400), Area_Water = c(40,50,60,70), Area_Forest = 
                     c(150,250,350,450))

# Hack
df$new <- as.character(1:nrow(df))
Scenarios <- df$new
names(Scenarios) <- df$Scenarios


library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(h4("Updating duplicate entries"),
                selectInput("scenario", "Scenario", Scenarios, selectize = 
                                FALSE), # Using Scenarios not df$Scenarios
                numericInput("crop", "Crop Area", min = 0, max = 1000, value 
                             = "", step = 0.5), # Set value to blank on start-up
                numericInput("water", "Water Area", min = 0, max = 1000, 
                             value = "", step = 0.5), # Set value to blank on start-up
                numericInput("forest", "Forest Area", min = 0, max = 1000, 
                             value = "", step = 0.5) # Set value to blank on start-up
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$scenario,
                 updateNumericInput(session,"crop", "Crop Area", 
                                    max= 50000, min= 0, value =
                                        df$Area_Crop[Scenarios ==input$scenario],step = 0.1))

    observeEvent(input$scenario,
                 updateNumericInput(session,"water", "Water Area",     
                                    min = 0, max = 1000,value =
                                        df$Area_Water[Scenarios==input$scenario],step = 0.1))

    observeEvent(input$scenario,
                 updateNumericInput(session,"forest", "Forest Area", 
                                    min= 0, max = 1000,value = 
                                        df$Area_Forest[Scenarios==input$scenario],step = 0.1))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If you type `Scenarios` in the console you will see what is happening:

```
> Scenarios
  Land   Land   Land Land_1 
   "1"    "2"    "3"    "4"
```

Basically the names displayed in the selectInput are as they were but the values behind them are now unique which allows the rest of your app to work.

Comment: This answer was more to see that it could be done than a best practice.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the trick. With regards to you, I will go through it piece by piece and try to understand the code. And yes I have a lot to learn.

Comment: Good luck Jitu!